# Dia command line not working on OSX

Tags: macos, command-line, dia

I've got a problem with using Dia from the command line on OSX 10.7.4. I downloaded and installed the OSX dmg from http://dia-installer.de/download/macosx.html I've been using it to create graphics for a paper and absolutely love it.

I'm using a makefile to call pdflatex, bibtex, and R so that that it will build everything from scratch if need be, but can't get Dia's command line to work.

I want to use the command line with -e and -t to export the graphics to a specific directory so that pdflatex can put them in the pdf. (http://dia-installer.de/doc/en/re01.html)

The problem that I'm running into is that anytime I call it from the terminal, it brings up the GUI. Even if I give move to /Applications/Dia.app/Content/Resources/bin/ and use the command "./dia -v". It gives me a bunch of errors about "Input method" and then shows the GUI.

I looked on the Dia FAQ and it has a lot of information for the Windows command line, but nothing for OSX.

I'm hoping that someone here has run into this before and knows how to get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming problem, so belongs on apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Answered on apple.stackexchange.com: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56749/dia-command-line-not-working/62640#62640 Could someone mark the question as answered here?